# Here maps API routing api "linkid prefix not valid"

Tags: rest, maps, here-api

I use HERE Maps Routing REST API 7.2. When I try to execute "getlinkinfo", I get the message "linkid prefix not valid".

Here is example of request (use your token and app id):

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?linkids=1048943660&linkattributes=speedLimit,functionalClass,speedCategory&token=my_token&app_id=my_app_id

Comment: You should either add a "+" or a "-" for LinkIds and linkAttributes does not support speed category, Also getLinkInfo is a Beta end point, for Speed Limits you can try using the Platform Data Extension API, https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?linkids=-1048943660&linkattributes=speedLimit,functionalClass&app_id=&app_code=

Comment: Looks like it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either add a "+" or a "-" for LinkIds and linkAttributes does not support speed category, Also getLinkInfo is a Beta end point, for Speed Limits you can try using the Platform Data Extension API, route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/…